# Is LayoutInflater.inflate() synchronous?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

That is, will it inflate the layout immediately in a blocking way, and call `onInflateFinished()` before returning, or does it return immediately and schedule the inflation for later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Inflate` is synchronous. There's no point of it to be asynchronous, not to mention getting return value, would become quite complicated.

[See docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29):

> **Returns:**
>
> The root View of the inflated hierarchy. If root was supplied, this is the root View; otherwise it is the root of the
> inflated XML file.